# Unexplained deletion of my edit

Tags: support

I recently asked a question about [Hitchcock, Stewart and Grant](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79201/hitchcock-stewart-and-grant) at the regular site (not the Meta site). The question was, what's the source of the often-repeated statement that after completing Vertigo, Hitchcock felt that Stewart looked too old, and decided not to work with him again.

Someone answered my question, citing page 138 in a certain book. The author of the answer said that she had not seen page 138; she had just seen another author cite page 138. I edited that answer by attaching an image of page 138, to show that that page was actually irrelevant to my question and the author who cited it had made (let's suppose) a mistake.

I first received notice that only I could view the edit until the edit had been reviewed.

But now when I check that page, I do not see the edit or the notice about review. It seems to be gone. Did someone delete my edit? Who and why?

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/67327 It was rejected. You don't get a notice of it. The closest thing you get is the +2 rep event if it's accepted.

Answer (score 6):

It was rejected by 2 of the 3 reviewers, both giving the following reason:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

You shouldn't really use edits to change the intent or argue against the validity of the claims made in an answer.  Edits are primarily for correcting language or improving formatting - but in some cases its appropriate to add reinforcing references, quotes or pictures.  They shouldn't really be used as a method of comment or disagreement.

If you think the answer has incorrect statements, you have a number of better avenues such as commenting or downvoting.

In many cases, especially if the original answerer doesn't respond to your critique, it is appropriate to write your own improved answer.  The community here can then vote to show which one they think is the best.

Comment: I don't follow the logic. I imagine that the author of that answer would have attached the image if she could have. I wasn't intending to argue with her. I was intending to continue down the path she started down. How would a down vote tell another reader that the citation she saw did not provide the source?

Comment: @Chaim ... in the opinion of 2 (experienced) reviewers your edit was going further than an edit should and was going against the original intent of the answer.  I'm sure that you are correct that the author would have attached the image and corrected their post ... however we don't *know* that for sure.  Its not for us to decide that for someone else.  The correct approach is either to comment and wait ... or create your own post.

Comment: @Chaim ... besides ... whether they are correct or not ... that was the outcome of the review process here, and why your edit wasn't approved.

Comment: @Chaim You can't change the content of someones answer, if there is anything wrong about it, you can flag,down vote or add a comment clearing it

Comment: @irsha On some previous occasion, and on ELU, I submitted an answer and then received notice that someone had edited my answer. I received some kind of automatic option to accept or reject the edit. I thought that my edits would put the author of that Movies & TV answer into the same position. In the course of this conversation here and now, someone sent me the link to do what I had intended to do. But helpfully, someone has now deleted the link, and of course after a few days my enthusiasm for the whole thing has flagged.

Comment: @iandotkelly Please see my previous comment.

Comment: @Chaim ... I don't know why you were not informed, the system here is identical to the rest of StackExchange.  The link you were shared is here: https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/67327